# Swinject error binding to date picker selection

Tags: swift, swiftui, swinject

I have a SwiftUI view that uses a date picker.

I am trying to update my model via the date picker.  The model is "Injected" via swinject, however I feel like something is slightly missing.

The error is:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Published<Date>.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding<Date>'
```

My view has the following code:

```
@Injected var viewModel: SignupViewModel
...
DatePicker("",selection: viewModel.$birthday, displayedComponents: [.date]).datePickerStyle(.wheel).environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: "en-GB"))
                .padding()
```

Model

```
import Foundation

public class SignupViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var birthday: Date = Date()

    @Injected var services: Services

}
```

The @Injected code is a property wrapper as follows

```
import Foundation
import Swinject

public struct Injection {
    public static let container = Container()
}

@propertyWrapper public struct Injected<Dependency> {
    public let wrappedValue: Dependency
 
    public init() {
        self.wrappedValue = Injection.container.resolve(Dependency.self)!
    }
}
```

My container in the App

```
    public init() {
        Injection.container.register(SignupRouter.self) { _ in
            return SignupRouter()
        }
        Injection.container.register(SignupViewModel.self) { _ in
            return SignupViewModel()
        }

    }
```

I have tried both $viewModel.birthday and viewModel.$birthday

As a side note, this does work if I change @Injected to @ObservedObject and create the model, so it's as if the @Injected isn't seeing the "type"?

I appreciate this is a gap in my knowledge so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a projected value in the property wrapper to support Binding instead of publisher

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/) is a good article. You don't need 3rd parties for DI it is quite simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Solved below.

I actually pulled this from [Factory](https://github.com/hmlongco/Factory) which I think I am going to start using instead of trying to hack around with Swinject.

```
@propertyWrapper public struct Injected<T>: DynamicProperty where T: ObservableObject {
    @StateObject private var dependency: T
    public init() {
        self._dependency = StateObject(wrappedValue: Injection.container.resolve(T.self)!)
    }
    public var wrappedValue: T {
        get { return dependency }
    }
    public var projectedValue: ObservedObject<T>.Wrapper {
        return self.$dependency
    }
}
```